# Environment variables with special characters breaks the toml file

Tags: configuration, config, toml

`$env{}` method is used to get environment variables as values for the configuration in the toml file.

```
con_password = "$env{CRED_PASSWORD}"
```

if `CRED_PASSWORD` is `"admin"` then it is fine, but say CRED_PASSWORD is `"admin$"` then it will break. We can use the  `"admin\\$"` it will work, but `CRED_PASSWORD = "ad\\$min\\$"` breaks. do we have any solutions to not to use escape characters and handle this?

incase if we have a solution, with escape characters,
In terms of user experience is there any specific config to address this without escaping characters?